# How do I execute inline javascript in HTML returned from an ajax call - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

very often I need to run some javascript on HTML contents returned from an ajax call.  Just dumping it in a div doesn't seem to work. Whats the best way to do it? LIke lets say I return teh following HTML code:

```
<div><input type="text" id="someID" /></div>
<script language="javascript">
$('#someID').somefunction();
</script>
```

Comment: call that function within ajax `success:` segment

Answer (score 1):

You should be using success event handlers. For example if you were using `load()` you'd do something like:

```
$('#foo').load('/my/ajax/stuff', function() {
    $('#someID').somefunction();
});
```

For setting up form elements I generally create a setup function and call it on ready and ajax complete

```
function setup_form() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker();
}

$(setup_form);
$.ajaxComplete(setup_form);
```

This will now setup your form elements on `document.ready` as well as when an ajax request completes.